# Find the approximate value in the vector

Tags: r

I have a number of the vector with the numbers.

```
test <- 0.495

vector <- c(0.5715122, 2.2860487, 5.1436096, 9.1441949)
```

This vector is the need to take an approximate number to the number 0.495.
Help me.

Comment: Please try to define what you need a little clearer. Do you need to find the number within the vector that is the closest to the test value?

Comment: @SergeyOrlov I find your avatar picture off-putting and distasteful.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you want to extract the value from a vector that is closest to your `test` value.

```
vector[which.min(abs(vector - test))]
#[1] 0.5715122
```

If two different values could be closest, you could do this:

```
vector <- c(0.5715122, 2.2860487, 5.1436096, 9.1441949, 0.4184878)
tol <- sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
vector[which(abs(vector - test) - min(abs(vector - test)) < tol)]
#[1] 0.5715122 0.4184878
```

`tol` is a tolerance accounting for floating point accuracy and usually chosen based on `help(".Machine")`.

Comment: I've started to wonder if `which.min` (as convenient as it is) is the right function for these types of jobs. What if (big __if__) two values are the same absolute distance away from the test value? Why not `which(... == min(...))`?

Comment: @bouncyball Then you'd need to consider floating point accuracy. You could do something like `vector[which(abs(vector - test) - min(abs(vector - test)) < tol)]`.

Comment: thanks for elucidating, and including it in your answer.